# file extension dependend actions

Tags: ruby, file, directory

I want to check if a directory has a ".ogg" or ".m4a" file. In every case the dir is empty before starting a download session. So it just can have one "ogg" or one "m4a" file.

I tried out this code to fetch the filename:

```
def self.get_filename
    if File.exists?('*.ogg')
      file = Dir.glob('*.ogg')
      @testfile = file[0]
      @filename = File.basename(@testfile,File.extname(@testfile))
    end
    if File.exists?('*.m4a')
      file = Dir.glob('*.m4a')
      @testfile = file[0]
      @filename = File.basename(@testfile,File.extname(@testfile))
    end
  end
```

Sadly the filename is actual empty. Maybe anyone knows why?

Comment: In `File.exists?('*.ogg')` I think the argument should be the real file name, not the regular expression like syntax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need `Dir.glob` instead.

```
Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/*.ogg') do |ogg_file|
  @testfile = ogg_file
  @filename = File.basename(@testfile,File.extname(@testfile))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`File#exists?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-exists-3F) does not support regular expressions.

You can do this instead:

```
if Dir["*.rb"].any?
  #....
```